# Why is there a structural difference between the bicuspid and tricuspid valve?

Tags: cardiology, human-physiology, circulatory-system

There are three cusps in the tricuspid valve and only two in the bicuspid valve? Why is there such a structural difference? Does it have anything to do with that there is oxygenated blood on the left side and deoxygenated on the right?

Comment: Because that is how the heart evolved. You should really rephrase your question to "Is there a functional reason for the observed structural differences of the bicuspid and tricuspid valve (in humans/mammals)?"